# Select2 - enforce one liner for multiple options selected

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-select2

I have a Select2 dropdown that contains many options (i.e. 50 states). If the user selects 40 of them, the dropdown becomes really tall with all the options listed. Is there a way to hide all the options when it overflows the given width so that it will say something like "40 of 50 selected) instead?

Also is there a way to 'select all' and 'unselect all' quickly without going through all the items manually?